# TextLayout framework prevent unselect when pressing menu button

Tags: text, actionscript, flash, tlf

For example we create a TextFlow element with some text in it. We make it editable. How can I prevent the text from deselecting when pressing the bold button.

```
var text:String = "<b>hallo</b><ol><li>1</li><li>2</li></ol>";  
var textFlow:TextFlow;  
    textFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow(text, TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT);
var containerController:ContainerController = new ContainerController(this, 400, 400);           

textFlow.flowComposer = new StandardFlowComposer();
textFlow.flowComposer.addController(containerController);
textFlow.format = new TextLayoutFormat();
textFlow.interactionManager = new EditManager();                    
textFlow.flowComposer.updateAllControllers();
```

How is it possible to prevent the EditManager (extends SelectionManager) from unselecting text when pressing another Button (Sprite) that is added on the container itself or another container.

**If you click outside of the selection it will deselect the current selection. How can this behaviour prevented?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selectionstate doesn't reset only the focus which does the blue color formatting.

```
textFlow.focus()
```

Does the trick.